# Pasting image from clipboard in Angular doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to retrieve the Files elements from the ClipboardEvent in Angular when copy/pasting an image to a textaera.

Using the (paste)="onPaste($event)" binding, when looking to the console I only get back empty files array:

[image]

Here is the [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kbwjiy) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: What browser are you using? I can assess the FileList of your StackBlitz in Chrome but not Edge.

Comment: That's strange, I tried it on Firefox (73.0) and Chrome (80.0) on Windows 10 v1909 and both are giving me an empty array when right clicking the image/copy and pasting in the textaera. :/

Comment: Actually it didn’t give the correct file name. I could get the value with: let files = e.clipboardData.files;


console.log(files[0].name);   but it had image.png for the name

Comment: Well at least you got something. :) What browser version are you using?

Comment: I'm not on that PC now, so can't check. Was latest Chrome On Windows. What details do you need of the file? Name or more?

Comment: Only the data, I'm aiming to upload the pasted image to an API. I just tried the example on Ubuntu on another computer, same behavior on my side: empty array. :/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't care about the console log. it's just a bug with the console.

Try this :

```
onPaste(e: any ) {
    const items = (e.clipboardData || e.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
    let blob = null;
    for (const item of items) {
      if (item.type.indexOf('image') === 0) {
        blob = item.getAsFile();
        console.log(blob); // Prints your files
      }
    }
}
```

Stackblitz Example : [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-textarea-paste-event-images)

PS : If you want the "name" of pasted items, you'll need to solicit input from the user. because Clipboard API doesn't support it